# What is the difference between a module and a script in Python?

Tags: python, scripting, module

Think the title summarizes the question :-)

Comment: Amazing question.

Comment: I think one of the biggest difference that's not mentioned from other sources when I googled "script vs module python" is its handling of `sys.path`. (1) When the file is running as a (top level) script, it prepends the **script’s directory** to `sys.path` and (2) when it's run as a module, prepends the **current working directory** to `sys.path` ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)). This SO post appeared in my google search result, and I find this difference very helpful, so noting it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A script is generally a directly executable piece of code, run by itself.  A module is generally a library, imported by other pieces of code.

Note that **there's no internal distinction** -- both are executable and importable, although library code often won't do anything (or will just run its unit tests) when executed directly and importing code designed to be a script will cause it to execute, hence the common `if __name__ == "__main__"` test.

Comment: Yep.  Also, as long as we're talking distinctions, I would call it a program (not a script) unless its primary use was to script the actions of other programs.

Answer (score 31):

Any Python module may be executed as a script. The only significant difference is that when imported as a module the filename is used as the basis for the module name whereas if you execute it as a script the module is named `__main__`.

This distinction makes it possible to have different behaviour when imported by enclosing script specific code in a block guarded by `if __name__=="__main__"`. This has been known to cause confusion when a user attempts to import the main module under its own name rather than importing `__main__`.

A minor difference between scripts and modules is that when you import a module the system will attempt to use an existing .pyc file (provided it exists and is up to date and for that version of Python) and if it has to compile from a .py file it will attempt to save a .pyc file. When you run a .py file as script it does not attempt to load a previously compiled module, nor will it attempt to save the compiled code. For this reason it may be worth keeping scripts small to minimise startup time.

Comment: I suggest to replace the phrase *executed as a script* by just *executed*, maybe also the remaining occurrences of *script* by *program* as suggested in the [comment of ʇsәɹoɈ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996110/what-is-the-difference-between-a-module-and-a-script-in-python#comment3060238_2996170)

Answer (score 1):

common: the code under `__name__ == "__main__"` guard will be executed.

differences:

1. invoke path is different: sys.argv[0] and sys.path[0]

`python -m` will use the search path (PYTHONPATH), and you can execute the code anywhere.

`python script.py` will assume using the same location with the script as the `sys.path[0]` (first search path), and relative imports may fail (e.g., if dependent module is in parent dir, and parent dir is not in search path). Whereas `python -m` will use the root of the python lib as the `sys.path[0]`

2. module is meant to be reused. script is usually one-off thing.

example code:

```
import sys

def main():
    print("path", sys.path)
    print("argv", sys.argv[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and have a dir structure:

```
$ tree tmp
tmp
├── __init__.py
└── hello.py
```

and try it yourself.