# What is __main__.py?

Tags: python

What is the `__main__.py` file for, what sort of code should I put into it, and when should I have one?

Comment: Also see the section [main-py-in-python-packages](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#main-py-in-python-packages) in the docs.

Answer (score 477, accepted):

Often, a Python program is run by naming a .py file on the command line:

```
$ python my_program.py
```

You can also create a directory or zipfile full of code, and include a `__main__.py`.  Then you can simply name the directory or zipfile on the command line, and it executes the `__main__.py` automatically:

```
$ python my_program_dir
$ python my_program.zip
# Or, if the program is accessible as a module
$ python -m my_program
```

You'll have to decide for yourself whether your application could benefit from being executed like this.

---

Note that a `__main__` *module* usually doesn't come from a `__main__.py` file. It can, but it usually doesn't. When you run a script like `python my_program.py`, the script will run as the `__main__` module instead of the `my_program` module. This also happens for modules run as `python -m my_module`, or in several other ways.

If you saw the name `__main__` in an error message, that doesn't necessarily mean you should be looking for a `__main__.py` file.

Comment: I found `python -m program_dir` and `python program_dir` a little different: the latter never runs `__init__.py` in the directory (if there is one).

Comment: @brk: That doesn't seem to be the case now. I just tried `python3 program_dir` and it ran `__init__.py`.

Comment: @mk12 I just tried it I can confirm @brk's findings:
`python3 dir` runs `__main__.py` but not `__init__.py`, whereas `python3 -m dir` runs both.

Comment: @mk12 Probably you had some code within `__main__.py` which has triggered the import of `__init__.py`

Comment: I place `__main__.py` in the root of project, so developer can run `python .` and voila!

Comment: @brk the two behave differently (and the distinction is actually important, since it can lead to bugs). I have added an answer below to show this difference, in case it interests any future readers.

Comment: Good answer. Also helpful to read the answer by @TasosPapastylianou re: relative imports.

Comment: How to call the main function in `__main__.py` within code? Because I get an error saying "Module has no attribute __main__".

Comment: What I would like to know, is it is possible to run `__main__.py` with `__name__` set to anything other than `"__main__"`? I have encountered a `__main__.py` with `if __name__ == "__main__"` in it, and I'm thinking this is completely redundant? `__name__` in `__main__.py` can never be anything other than `"__main__"`? ... ah I've just noticed one of the other answers has confirmed this is correct.

Answer (score 196):

### What is the `__main__.py` file for?

When creating a Python module, it is common to make the module execute some functionality (usually contained in a `main` function) when run as the entry point of the program. This is typically done with the following common idiom placed at the bottom of most Python files:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # execute only if run as the entry point into the program
    main()
```

You can get the same semantics for a Python package with `__main__.py`, which might have the following structure:

```
.
└── demo
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __main__.py
```

To see this, paste the below into a Python 3 shell:

```py
from pathlib import Path

demo = Path.cwd() / 'demo'
demo.mkdir()

(demo / '__init__.py').write_text("""
print('demo/__init__.py executed')

def main():
    print('main() executed')
""")

(demo / '__main__.py').write_text("""
print('demo/__main__.py executed')

from demo import main

main()
""")
```

We can treat demo as a package and actually import it, which executes the top-level code in the `__init__.py` (but not the `main` function):

```py
>>> import demo
demo/__init__.py executed
```

When we use the package as the entry point to the program, we perform the code in the `__main__.py`, which imports the `__init__.py` first:

```sh
$ python -m demo
demo/__init__.py executed
demo/__main__.py executed
main() executed
```

You can derive this from the documentation. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) says:

> ## `__main__` — Top-level script environment
>
> `'__main__'` is the name of the scope in which top-level code executes.
> A module’s `__name__` is set equal to `'__main__'` when read from standard
> input, a script, or from an interactive prompt.
>
> A module can discover whether or not it is running in the main scope
> by checking its own `__name__`, which allows a common idiom for
> conditionally executing code in a module when it is run as a script or
> with `python -m` but not when it is imported:
>
> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>      # execute only if run as a script
>      main()
> ```
>
> For a package, the same effect can be achieved by including a
> `__main__.py` module, the contents of which will be executed when the module is run with `-m`.

#### Zipped

You can also zip up this directory, including the `__main__.py`, into a single file and run it from the command line like this - but note that zipped packages can't execute sub-packages or submodules as the entry point:

```py
from pathlib import Path

demo = Path.cwd() / 'demo2'
demo.mkdir()

(demo / '__init__.py').write_text("""
print('demo2/__init__.py executed')

def main():
    print('main() executed')
""")

(demo / '__main__.py').write_text("""
print('demo2/__main__.py executed')

from __init__ import main

main()
""")
```

Note the subtle change - we are importing `main` from `__init__` instead of `demo2` - this zipped directory is not being treated as a package, but as a directory of scripts. So it must be used without the `-m` flag.

Particularly relevant to the question - `zipapp` causes the zipped directory to execute the `__main__.py` by default - and it is executed first, before `__init__.py`:

```sh
$ python -m zipapp demo2 -o demo2zip
$ python demo2zip
demo2/__main__.py executed
demo2/__init__.py executed
main() executed
```

Note again, this zipped directory is not a package - you cannot import it either.

Comment: Would you use `if __name__ == '__main__'` within `__main__.py`? Or is it unecessary?

Comment: I believe it's redundant.

Comment: It's redundant, as you would never import `__main.py__` into another module. The `if __name__ == "__main__"` protective clause serves the purpose of protecting module-level code from being run on import. This wouldn't happen when you're building a `__main__.py` file.

Comment: I find it useful because I (and other users of the site) can recreate the files by simply pasting the code into Python interpreter.

Answer (score 48):

Some of the answers here imply that given a "package" directory (with or without an explicit `__init__.py` file), containing a `__main__.py` file, there is no difference between running that directory with the `-m` switch or without.

The big difference is that *without* the `-m` switch, **the "package" directory is first added to the path** (i.e. sys.path), and then the files are run normally, **without package semantics**.

Whereas *with* the `-m` switch, **package semantics (including relative imports) are honoured**, and the package directory itself **is never added to the system path**.

This is a very important distinction, both in terms of whether relative imports will work or not, but more importantly in terms of dictating **what will be imported in the case of unintended shadowing of system modules**.

---

Example:

Consider a directory called `PkgTest` with the following structure

```
:~/PkgTest$ tree
.
├── pkgname
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── secondtest.py
│   └── testmodule.py
└── testmodule.py
```

where the `__main__.py` file has the following contents:

```
:~/PkgTest$ cat pkgname/__main__.py
import os
print( "Hello from pkgname.__main__.py. I am the file", os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )
print( "I am being accessed from", os.path.abspath( os.curdir ) )
from  testmodule import main as firstmain;     firstmain()
from .secondtest import main as secondmain;    secondmain()
```

(with the other files defined similarly with similar printouts).

If you run this without the `-m` switch, this is what you'll get. Note that the relative import fails, but more importantly note that **the wrong testmodule has been chosen** (i.e. relative to the working directory):

```
:~/PkgTest$ python3 pkgname
Hello from pkgname.__main__.py. I am the file ~/PkgTest/pkgname/__main__.py
I am being accessed from ~/PkgTest
Hello from testmodule.py. I am the file ~/PkgTest/pkgname/testmodule.py
I am being accessed from ~/PkgTest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "pkgname/__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .secondtest import main as secondmain
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Whereas with the -m switch, you get what you (hopefully) expected:

```
:~/PkgTest$ python3 -m pkgname
Hello from pkgname.__main__.py. I am the file ~/PkgTest/pkgname/__main__.py
I am being accessed from ~/PkgTest
Hello from testmodule.py. I am the file ~/PkgTest/testmodule.py
I am being accessed from ~/PkgTest
Hello from secondtest.py. I am the file ~/PkgTest/pkgname/secondtest.py
I am being accessed from ~/PkgTest
```

---

---

Note: In my honest opinion, running without `-m` should be avoided. In fact I would go further and say that I would create any `executable packages` in such a way that they would fail unless run via the `-m` switch.

In other words, I would only import from 'in-package' modules explicitly via 'relative imports', assuming that all other imports represent system modules. If someone attempts to run your package without the `-m` switch, the relative import statements will throw an error, instead of silently running the wrong module.

Comment: Explanation of the implications for relative imports is very helpful, Thanks.

Comment: Shameless plug: In case it interests anyone, [here is a nice template I made](https://github.com/tpapastylianou/executable-python-package-template) for creating such self-contained, executable python packages. :)

Comment: wait but if you wanted to use the `testmodule` the one from `PkgTest/pkgname` how will you do it forcing `-m`?

Comment: @ShifraSec You mean in the code? You can import it using a relative import, i.e. `from . testmodule import main` (note the dot!). Alternatively you can use the package name explicitly and say, e.g. `from pkgname import testmodule`. If you want to import _both_ in your code, you can load them under different names, e.g. `import testmodule as testmodule1; from pkgname import testmodule as testmodule2`.

Comment: @Tasos Papastylianou 
ooh you are right, that's a basic thing I confused myself for a moment

Comment: @ShifraSec no worries. Not at all; it's the kind of thing you have to play around with until you get a good grip for it. :)

Answer (score 39):

You create `__main__.py` in `yourpackage` to make it executable as:

```
$ python -m yourpackage
```

Comment: `-m` works if only the program is accessible as a module, else you could use `python <yourpackage>` NOTE: without `-m` option

Comment: @BenyaminJafari it is not possible to write command line Python program that is not accessible as [a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996110/what-is-the-difference-between-a-module-and-a-script-in-python). Maybe you've meant `package`?

Comment: when we create a Python package which contains the __main__.py, to run it `python -m <yourproject>` doesn't work, `-m` is a redundant option, but `python <yourpackage>` works well.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari The -m flag does make a difference in some cases. Executing from directory `a` and assuming script `a/b/c/__main__.py`... `python -m b.c` will execute from the directory `a` and the main script's imports will be relative to `a`. But `python b/c` will execute from the import scope of dir `c` and so any imports like in the main script like `import b.d` will fail.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari this is dangerous advice. There is a very important difference between running with or without the `-m` switch. I have added an answer below to clarify this, for any future readers wondering about the difference.

Answer (score 38):

`__main__.py` is used for python programs in zip files. The `__main__.py` file will be executed when the zip file in run. For example, if the zip file was as such:

```
test.zip
     __main__.py
```

and the contents of `__main__.py` was

```
import sys
print "hello %s" % sys.argv[1]
```

Then if we were to run `python test.zip world` we would get `hello world` out.

So the `__main__.py` file run when python is called on a zip file.

Answer (score 19):

If your script is a directory or ZIP file rather than a single python file, `__main__.py` will be executed when the "script" is passed as an argument to the python interpreter.