# Running function in __main__ .py from command line

Tags: python

I've got the following __main__.py file:

```
def all():
    print "hello world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "bar"
```

How can I run function `all` from the command line? The following don't seem to work:

```
python -c "import __main__; __main__.all()"
python .
```

I am not allowed to modify the __main__.py file. 
(This is for a FLOSS project that I'm trying to contribute to)

Comment: Should it say `foo()` instead of `all()`?

Comment: You're right, it's all(), and not foo(). I assumed the name had no importance. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__main__` module is always part of a package. Include the package name when importing:

```
python -c 'from package.__main__ import all; all()'
```

Demo:

```
$ mkdir testpackage
$ touch testpackage/__init__.py
$ cat << EOF > testpackage/__main__.py
> def all():
>     print "Hello world!"
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     all()
> EOF
$ python testpackage
Hello world!
$ python -c 'from testpackage.__main__ import all; all()'
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do this but if `__main__.py` is in your working directory:

```
python -c "import imp; trick = imp.load_source('__main__', './__main__.py'); trick.all()"
```

If your file sits in a directory like `foo/__main__.py` then you can do

```
python -c "import imp; trick = imp.load_source('foo.__main__', 'foo/__main__.py'); trick.all()"
```

See also [What is __main__.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py) and [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `setup.py` to install this package, you can add a command-line entry point for the `all` function:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='1.0',
    packages=['mypackage'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mypackage_all = mypackage.__main__:all',
        ],
    },
)
```

After running `python setup.py develop` or `python setup.py install`, you will be able to call the `all` function using `mypackage_all`:

```
$ mypackage_all
hello world!
```