# Running a script from a package

Tags: python

I'm new to python coming from java. I created a folder called: 'Project'. In 'Project' I created many packages (with `__init__.py` files) like 'test1' and 'tests2'. 'test1' contains a python script file `.py` that uses scripts from 'test2' (import a module from test2). I want to run a script `x.py` in 'test1' from command line. How can I do that?

Edit: if you have better recommendations on how I can better organize my files I would be thankful. (notice my java mentality)

Edit: I need to run the script from a bash script, so I need to provide full paths.

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly just give your script execution permissions (`./x.py` in *NIX systems) or type `python x.py`.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably several ways to achieve what you want.

One thing that I do when I need to make sure the module paths are correct in an executable scripts is to get the parent directory and insert in the module search path (`sys.path`):

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))

import test1 # next imports go here...
from test2 import something
# any import what works from the parent dir will work here
```

This way you are safe to run your scripts without worrying how the script is called.

Answer (score 1):

Python code is organized into modules and packages. A module is just a `.py` file that can contain class definitions, function definitions and variables. A package is a directory with a `__init__.py` file.

A standard Python project might look something like this:

```
thingsproject/
  README
  setup.py
  doc/
     ...
  things/
    __init__.py
    animals.py
    vegetables.py
    minerals.py
  test/
    test_animals.py
    test_vegetables.py
    test_minerals.py
```

The setup.py file describes the metadata about your project. See [Writing the Setup Script](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) and particularly the section on [installing scripts](http://docs.python.org/2.6/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts).

[Entry points](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) exist to help distribute command line tools in Python. An entry point is defined in `setup.py` like this:

```
setup(
    name='thingsproject',
    ....
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['dog = things.animals:dog_main_function']
    },
    ...
)
```

The effect is that when the package is installed using `python setup.py install` a script is automatically created in some reasonable place according to your OS, such as `/usr/local/bin`. The script then calls the `dog_main_function` in the `animals` module of the `things` package.

Yet another Python convention to consider is have a [`__main__.py` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py). This signifies the "main" script within a directory or zip file full of python code. This is a good place to define a command line interface to your code using the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) parser for command line arguments.

Good and up-to-date information on the somewhat muddled world of Python packaging can be found in the [Python Packaging User Guide](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/).