# Importing a Python package from a script with the same name

Tags: python

I'm trying to re-organize my Python project by moving scripts from the package directory into a top level script directory. After these changes, this is what my project hierarchy looks like:

```
MyProject/
    setup.py

    scripts/
        my_package.py

    my_package/
        __init__.py
        module_foo.py
```

Notice how the script and the package have the same name.

The script `my_package.py` looks something like this:

```
# MyProject/scripts/my_package.py
import os
try:
    import my_package
    print os.path.abspath(my_package.__file__)
except ImportError as e:
    print e
```

When we run the above script the interpreter imports the current module rather than the *package* of the same name (*note:* the package `my_package` has already been installed into `site-packages` as an egg and our virtual environment is properly activated.)

How can I import the *package* `my_package` from the *script* `my_package.py` given they have the same name?

### Other Technical Info:

- Python 2.7.3
- Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS
- VirtualEnv 1.11.6

Comment: Change script name - it is the simplest solution.

Comment: Did you try add `os.path.append("..")` before calling `import my_package`

Comment: @furas is renaming the script really my only choice? Based on what I've read about the "absolute import" feature, the import syntax I used *should* work.

Comment: @user8708 I tried *sys*.path.append('..') and had no luck.

Comment: @AlfaZulu your `my_package` should be inside `scripts` to override path

Comment: your hierarchy doesn't really make sense. It's the `setup` script that should do the imports and pass relevant data from `my_package` module to `my_package` script. If `my_package` is your main script, why put it in a sub-directory in the first place? That's counterintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

For me it works with

```
sys.path.insert(0, '..')
```

since the import does something like `for path in sys.path:`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to rename `my_package.py`, using the canonical name for the core script for a module: `__main__.py`, and put it back in your module directory.  Then also arrange for the `my_package` executable to be automatically generated by defining an `entry_point` for it in your [`setup.py`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) file.
[Python Apps the Right Way: entry points and scripts, by Chris Warrick](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/) covers this in some depth.

See also [What is **main**.py? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py) to see some of the other ways of calling `my_package` that this also sets up automatically, like `python -m my_package`.