# What is the difference between __init__.py and __main__.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know of these two questions about `__init__.py` and `__main__.py`:

[What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271)

[What is __main__.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905)

But I don't really understand the difference between them. Or I could say I don't understand how they interact together.

Comment: The answers to the two questions you linked are completely different. What's your point of confusion?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

**__init__.py** is run when you *import* a package into a running python program. For instance, `import idlelib` within a program, runs `idlelib/__init__.py`, which does not do anything as its only purpose is to mark the idlelib directory as a package.  On the otherhand, `tkinter/__init__.py` contains most of the tkinter code and defines all the widget classes.

**__main__.py** is run as '__main__' when you *run* a package as the main program. For instance, `python -m idlelib` at a command line runs `idlelib/__main__.py`, which starts Idle.  Similarly, `python -m tkinter` runs `tkinter/__main__.py`, which has this line:

```
from . import _test as main
```

In this context, `.` is `tkinter`, so importing `.` imports `tkinter`, which runs `tkinter/__init__.py`.  `_test` is a function defined within that file.  So calling `main()` (next line) has the same effect as running `python -m tkinter.__init__` at the command line.

Comment: Why does `tkinter` have a lot of code in the `__init__.py` file while `idlelib` have no code there? Is there a reason why you would sometimes want to have code in `__init__.py` but other times not?

Comment: Code in `package/__init__.py` makes the `import package` actually do something.  Before 3.0, `Tkinter` was a module, not a package.  In 3.0, the code in `Tkinter.py` was put in  `tkinter/__init__.py, so the only change needed was `import tkinter` instead of `import Tkinter`.

Comment: @Terry Jan Reedy: Could you please explain "So calling main() (next line) has the same effect as running python -m tkinter.__init__ at the command line" ..? Thanks.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye `tkinter` a package but the devs wanted `import tkinter` to give access to the pre-ttk widget set.  Sticking the code for this in __init__ was the easiet way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 13):

`__init__.py`, among other things, labels a directory as a python directory and lets you set variables on a package wide level.

`__main__.py`, among other things, is run if you try to run a compressed group of python files.  `__main__.py` allows you to execute packages.

Both of these answers were obtained from the answers you linked.  Is there something else you didn't understand about these things?