# Running python package as a module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a Python library called `blah` with a directory structure like:

```
blah/
├── blah/
   ├── __init__.py
   └── file.py
```

Currently, to run the code in file.py we have to run `python3 -m blah.file ...`. Is there any way to structure the library so that we can simply write `python3 -m blah ...`?

The library contains some utility scripts that will be called many times a day and the shorter command will save millions of keystrokes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327762/what-is-the-difference-between-init-py-and-main-py