# How to run a module inside a package, using relative imports?

Tags: pydev

**This question is specific to PyDev.** The package structure looks like this:

```
app
├── __init__.py
├── sub1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mod1.py
└── sub2
    ├── __init__.py
    └── mod2.py
```

The `mod1.py` module:

```python
from __future__ import print_function

def f():
    print('It works!')
```

The `mod2.py` module:

```python
from __future__ import absolute_import
from ..sub1 import mod1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mod1.f()
```

**Everything works beautifully from the shell**, the `python -m app.sub2.mod2` command prints:

```
It works!
```

as expected, all is fine. (The `from __future__ import absolute_import` line seems to have no effect: I can comment it out and everything still works just fine.)

If I click on `mod2` in the PyDev IDE and try to `Run As` > `Python Run`, I get

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

which is not surprising as the `-m` switch is not turned on by default. If I edit the Run/Debug settings for `mod2`: Arguments > VM Arguments and add `-m` here;  the `-m` is most likely passed to the python interpreter but now I get:

```
/usr/bin/python: Import by filename is not supported.
```

The `from __future__ import absolute_import` line seems to have no effect; it does not matter whether I comment it out or not; I am using Python 2.7.

I am out of ideas at this point.

- In PyDev, how can I run a module inside a package that uses relative
  imports?
- How should I change the settings once (globally) such that whenever I
  try to run a module inside a package, PyDev does the right thing?
  (That is, I don't have to individually specify the settings for each
  module that I wish to run.)

---

The developer in person confirmed that it is not possible in PyDev yet; I have opened a ticket for it.

[Running a module inside a package, using relative imports](https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/606)

---

**UPDATE:** As of Dec 2, 2016, the issue is resolved, see the accepted answer.

Comment: Seems like a pydev bug.  Having said that, perhaps you could try adding a `__main__.py` module to your top-level package, and write Python code that invokes your desired sub-module.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin Could you expand on the *"write Python code that invokes your desired sub-module"* part, please?

Comment: If you have a library that can also be used as an application, the cleanest way to separate app usage from library usage is to have a [`__main__.py`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py) file inside your top-level app.  You put a parser in there that can, for example, let you decide which submodule to execute.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't see how a `__main__.py` could resolve my problem in PyDev: There are many-many modules that I may want to execute inside a package. I am probably missing your point, sorry. :(

Comment: That's where the bit of coding comes in.  From the command line, or pydev, instead of `python -m app.sub2.mod2` you would do `python -m app sub2.mod2` (with a space instead of the first dot).  And then `__main__.py` could have `import sys; __import__('.'+sys.argv.pop(1))`, or something like that but with better error checking and reporting.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin OK. And how do I make PyDev to run `python -m app sub2.mod2` when I click on the `mod2.py` file and ask PyDev to run it? If I could do that somehow, then I could (most likely) make PyDev to run it as  `python -m app.sub2.mod2` and that definitely would work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think deeply enough about that part, and you're right -- in the IDE if that would work, then you could make your original approach work.  You could import differently based on whether the module is `__main__` but that is a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

In `PyDev 5.4.0`, there's now an option to run using the `-m` flag (which will import the module through its regular name and not as it was `__main__` so that relative imports will work there).

You can enable it at: `Preferences > PyDev > Run` (i.e.: this will enable it for all runs -- maybe in the future there'll be an option to make it per run, but for now it's set globally for all launches).

---

Original answer:

The problem is that you have relative imports in your main module and PyDev executes the file with `python path/to/file_to_execute.py` instead of `python -m my.module`.

A simple fix is doing a separate main module which in turn imports a main() function from that module and runs it (although again: it can't have relative imports in the module executed as `__main__` (this happens because the module is called `__main__` and thus cannot resolve a relative import because it wasn't actually imported with a name which can be used to resolve the relative import).

Another fix would be changing the launch configuration to add the `'-m my.module'` in the VM arguments (go to run > run configurations to do that -- but you have to do that for each main module you want to run, including unit-tests).

And the last fix would be changing PyDev itself (so, please create a ticket for that in the PyDev tracker: https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/ -- or submit a pull request, which would make adding that feature much faster ;) )

Comment: I have enabled the option in PyDev as you indicated, but when I "See resulting command-line" I still get `python -u /full/path/to/file.py` and still have the same issue as the OP. I have restarted Eclipse to see if I would need it to take effect - same thing.