# How to find out the starting point of code execution in any Python project?

Tags: python, debugging

I have been looking at various open source GitHub Python projects like, 
[`http-prompt`](https://github.com/eliangcs/http-prompt) and [Theano](https://github.com/Theano/Theano)

What I am not able to figure out is where their starting points are, so that I can debug them gracefully. Do I need to look in each and every file for the `__main__` method?

I am from Android background; so I was searching something related like `AndroidManifest.xml` from where I can get an idea as where the code is getting started, but I was unsuccessful in my attempts.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you please be a little more descriptive. I am a ""newbie"".

Comment: Can you please suggest some links for simpler projects?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Consider a standalone application which can be executed. Now, assume it has a complex directory structure. Now, can you please help me in locating the starting point of the Python application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114844/discussion-between-ali-waris-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways a Python script can be loaded:

- By import : `import mymodule`
- By commandline : `$ python mymodule.py`

In both cases all code inside the script is executed

Usually `if __name__ == '__main__':` defines the entry  point :

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    print('Started from commandline')
else:
    print('Imported as a module')
```

In a git project, you can try this to find all scripts made to be launched from command-line :

```
$ git grep "if __name__ ?== ?\W__main__\W"
```

Note that the project you mentioned, doesn't contain any explicitly defined entry point, instead the entry point script is generated at packaging time for distribution (see `setup.py` for this purpose)

Comment: Where do I need to look for the code ? In each module?? Please forgive me for being silly if I seem to..

Comment: Usually the project should be documented accordingly, because you may find several entry points in a project

Comment: The project http-prompt doesn't provide a standard way to execute from source, it uses function `cli(url, http_options)` in `http_prompt/cli.py`, this is defined in setup.py `entry_points` : `http-prompt=http_prompt.cli:cli`I recommend you install the project with `$ pip install http-prompt`

Comment: What if the code can be executed from source? How to get the start point of the code then?

Comment: Note that this refers to *scripts*, not *packages*, which may not have any `if __name__ == '__main__':` blocks.

Comment: If `if __name__ == '__main__':` is not present, any code outside a block is executed anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The Python equivalent of a manifest file is generally `setup.py`, so this is a good place to start looking. A package can:

- define scripts that should be installed, using [the `scripts` keyword](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-scripts-keyword-argument) (as [Theano does](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/setup.py#L178)); or
- use [the `entry_points` keyword](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html?highlight=entry_points#the-console-scripts-entry-point) to define a function that should be exposed to the command line (as [`http-prompt`](https://github.com/eliangcs/http-prompt/blob/master/setup.py#L56) does, pointing to [the `cli` function](https://github.com/eliangcs/http-prompt/blob/master/http_prompt/cli.py#L46)).

If neither of these is provided, the package is probably designed to be `import`ed rather than executed, in which case take a look at the usage examples along with the root `__init__.py` (e.g. [Theano's](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/__init__.py)), which will probably tell you what objects are exposed to the outside world. See [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more information on module structure.

However, Python is a dynamic, flexible language so there's no *"magic bullet"* to tell you where to look; there isn't e.g. a specific `main.py` file that must be defined, for example (although there is a `__main__.py` that *can* be defined, see [What is __main__.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py))