# How to get PiShow (Dropbox Slideshow for Raspberry Pi) work?

Tags: python, slideshow, dropbox

I would like to run this slideshow: 
https://github.com/8BitAce/PiShow

I have done all steps listed on the manual up to number 4. In point 5 he is talking about a file called "pishow.py". But there is no file like this in the folder. So I tried it with the file slideshow.py located in the folder pishow.

So with this file I also made step 5. But when I run now the final command to start this thing

```
python pishow/slideshow.py Images Photos/PiImages
```

nothing happens. 
I do this on a Raspberry Pi Model 3 with Raspbian Jessie Pixel on it. I would be so happy if someone can give me a hint!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that running `pishow.py` is the same as running the `__main__.py` module that is down in the pishow folder.

[What is __main__.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py)

So, even though there is not a pishow.py file as such, that's still the python command you run.