# Which .py file does 'python -m <module>' run?

Tags: python, module

According to the [python man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/python), if you add the **-m *module-name*** option when running the python interpreter, python "searches *sys.path*  for the named module and runs the corresponding *.py* file as a script." But for e.g. the module `unittest`, which is a folder located in `<Python folder>\Lib`, there are many .py files. Which of these is considered "the corresponding *.py* file"?

Comment: @vaultah I think it's incorrect to label this question as an "exact duplicate" of [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py). I agree that this question is similar, and the other question does contain an answer that also answers this question, so I'm for closing this question and referring to that question for that reason, but this question is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: I didn't label it as an "exact duplicate" -- the system did. What matters is the bold text above the link, saying **"This question already has an answer here:"**.

Comment: @vaultah I'm sorry if I accused you of putting that label there; I know that Stack Overflow does that. I don't like that it does, simply because it in many cases is incorrect (like in this case). Thank you for linking me to that other question by the way.