# I name a python file as "__main__.py", and I import __main__ in another file, can't run the functions in __main__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I create two python files named "test.py" and `__main__.py`.

in test.py:

```
import __main__
```

in `__main__.py`:

```
print(__name__)
```

but when I run test.py, it outputs nothing.

then, I change `__main__.py` to:

```
def main():
    print("ok")
```

and test.py:

```
import __main__
__main__.main()
```

When I run test.py, it appears an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/lyz/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    __main__.main()
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'main'
```

who can tell me why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py_) probably help you to understand "why"

Comment: I have a really bad feeling about naming a file \__main__ since this is really reserved for other purposes. Maybe someone could give a hint of the function of \__main__?

Comment: `__main__` is a special name and you should use it only for a module with special function. https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Comment: This is why `__main__.py` is a good name for a toplevel application that is not meant to be imported. Go with `__init__.py` for modules in distinct directories and you will be able to import it by naming the directory.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by the underscores, `__main__` is a magic module name. It refers to the module first executed by the Python interpreter. If you run `python test.py`, `__main__` will be the module formed by `test.py`.

Instead, rename your `__main__.py` to `main.py` and use `import main` and `main.main()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `python test.py` the interpreter treats "test.py" as `__main__` module and not `test` module. This is done even before reading the first line in "test.py". So when you write `import __main__` it just means `import test`.

You can test this by writing "__main__.py" as follow:

```
def main():
    print("__main__ imported")
```

Write "test.py" as:

```
import __main__

def main():
    print("test imported")

__main__.main()
```

Now run `python test.py` and you will see `test imported`

Answer (score 1):

You are never importing anything.  Since your own file is given the name `__main__` (this is true because `__name__` returns `'__main__'`), whatever name you give your file.

You are never actually importing anything but the file you are running:

Run this throught the interpreter to see what I mean.

```
>>>def hello(): print('HELLO')
...
>>>import __main__
>>>__main__.hello()
HELLO
>>>
>>>
>>>__main__
<module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

You can quite clearly see that `__main__` is an inbuilt command, and `__main__.py` and is never imported, only the original script.

> A module’s `__name__` is set equal to `'__main__'` when read from standard input, a script, or from an interactive prompt.

See [29.4. **main** — Top-level script environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

To fix the problem rename `__main__.py` to something that does not conflict with inbuilt commands.

Answer (score 1):

To import `__main__.py` you need to put it into a folder, which Python would consider a module folder then.

```
.
├── my_module
│   └── __main__.py
└── test.py
```

Then you should place `test.py` outside this folder and import `__main__.py` like this:

```py
# test.py
from my_module import __main__
...
```