# Fabric load fabfile as a module

Tags: python, fabric

My fabfile contains relative imports, thus it has to be loaded as a module.

It seems that fab loads the fabfile as standalone script, so the relative imports are not working.

Here is my folder structure:

```
scripts
 |-> __init__.py 
 |-> deployment
      |-> __init__.py
      |-> fabfile.py
 |-> other-module
```

To debug/test the fabfile I can load it using:

```
python -m scripts.deployment.fabfile
```

Is there a way to force the fab tool to load the fabfile as module?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make that happen, you need to add a `scripts/deployment/__main__.py`.

```
scripts
 |-> __init__.py 
 |-> deployment
      |-> __init__.py
      |-> __main__.py
      |-> fabfile.py
 |-> other-module
```

Supposing there's an entrypoint function inside your `scripts/deployment/fabfile.py` called `my_fabric_entry`, you can call it from `scripts/deployment/__main__.py` and it will do the trick.

```
$ cat scripts/deployment/__main__.py
from __future__ import print_function
from .fabfile import my_fabric_entry

print('About to call fabfile.my_fabric_entry()')
my_fabric_entry()

$ python -m scripts.deployment
About to call fabfile.my_fabric_entry()
```

Check this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/36320295/977593