# unittest, works locally, but not on a remote server, no module named x.__main__; 'x' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Tags: python, unit-testing, jenkins, module, python-unittest

I am working on a Jenkins CI/CD pipeline for my Python package. My project file hierarchy is as follows:

```
project/
- package_name
  - file1.py
  - file2.py
  - etc...
- tests
  - unit
    - __main__.py
    - __init__.py
    - test1.py
    - test2.py
```

All unit tests (I am using `unittest`) are run using a single command

`python -m tests.unit`

via adding `__init__.py` of the following content:

**contents**

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

and `__main__.py` which looks like this

**contents**

```
import unittest
import sys

sys.path.append('../..')

loader = unittest.TestLoader()
start_dir = '.'
suite = loader.discover(start_dir)
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

First, the path is changed to the `./tests/unit`. After that, the top directory is added to the import path so that the package can be imported in tests. This works as intended (i.e., all rests are executed by running `python -m test.unit` at the top of the project directory) on my personal laptop (Python 3.6.4).

However, when I use the same trick on a remote Jenkins server (Python 3.6.4 as well), I am getting the following error:

```
no module named test.unit.__main__; 'test.unit' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

I have researched the issue but none of the proposed solutions seems to be working in my case.

*How can I modify my code to create a test suite in `unittest` that will run without any issues locally and remotely?*

**EDIT**
I tried modifying the `PYTHONPATH` variable, but no success

Comment: If you are using unittest you can just run `python -m unittest discover`. You don't need the `__main__.py`. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface). You can probably just delete the contents of `__init__.py` as well.

Comment: @mark_s it does have the init file, the package is a legit Python package

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with Jenkins, and I feel a little goofy asking this, but the remote server isn't defaulting to Python 2.7 when running your code is it? Some of the Google responses for your error message associate it with Python version 2.x ..

Comment: @mark_s the same version of Python in both systems (3.6.4, local and remote)

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is not caused by the `python -m test.unit` vs `python -m tests.unit` typo (note the single letter difference)? At least the text of your question suggests that that may be case. If the typo is in your question, please edit it, and I will remove my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Why it does not work?

### 1.1. About `python -m` and `__main__.py`

When you run `python -m tests.unit`, what code will be ran by the python interpreter, is, in this order

```
tests.__init__.py
tests.unit.__init__.py
tests.unit.__main__.py
```

### 1.2. Reproducing the error

Now, if you remove the `__main__.py`, you will get the following error:

```
No module named tests.unit.__main__; 'tests.unit' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

This is almost the same message as you did get. If you have in your `sys.path` a folder that contain folder called `test` with structure like this (Note: the `test`-folder is not in prular, and there is no __main__.py!)

```
test
├── __init__.py
└── unit
    └── __init__.py
```

and run command

```
python -m test.unit
```

what python interpreter tries to run, in this order is

```
test.__init__.py
test.unit.__init__.py
test.unit.__main__.py <-- missing!
```

Since `test.unit.__main__.py` is missing, you will get error message

```
No module named test.unit.__main__; 'test.unit' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

which is the error message you are getting. So, the reason for your error message most probably, that you have somewhere in your `sys.path` directories a directory called `test` with the structure shown above, and you are trying to call `python -m test.unit` instead of `python -m tests.unit`.

## 2. How to make it work?

- Remove your `os.chdir` and `sys.path.append` hacks that you are using in your `__init__.py` and `__main__.py`.  At least, they are not needed for python unittest to work.
- Create unittests using the pattern shown in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) (by subclassing unittest.TestCase)
- Run your unit tests by

```
python -m unittest
```

Answer (score 1):

I can run the tests using this command:

```sh
python -m unittest discover
```

You should never need to run `os.chdir` or append to `sys.path` just to run your tests.

I replicated your project structure, like this:

```
.
├── package
│   └── module.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── unit
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_module.py
```

Notice how each directory under `tests/` has an `__init__.py` file, which is actually empty. It only needs to exist. Its existence makes that directory a module. For more use cases read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for).

You don't need `__main__.py`. That is for when you want to run `python3 -m package` from the command line (instead of `python3 package/module.py` or something like that). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py).

In this case unittest just needs the `__init__.py` files in the test dirs to work properly.

It is also important that the name of each test file begins with `test_`, as this is a naming convention that unittest looks for.

For reference, the contents of `module.py` looks like this:

```py
def method():
    return True
```

And the contents of `test_module.py` looks like this:

```py
from package.module import method
from unittest import TestCase

class TestMethod(TestCase):
    def test_method(self):
        self.assertTrue(method())
```

Making these modifications to your code will allow you to run your test suite in unittest without any issues locally and remotely.

Comment: thanks for your input. I am more interested to learn why importing tests as a module works in one place, but not the other.