# How can I start the main function of this Python module after installing it using pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have a Python 3 [project](https://bitbucket.org/altruix/rec2sqlite/src/i1/). I am developing it locally.

I tried to install it by `cd`ing into the project directory and then executing

```
pip3 install .
```

The resulting output was:

```
Processing /Users/XXXXX/dev/misc/rec2sqlite
Building wheels for collected packages: rec2sqlite
  Building wheel for rec2sqlite (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for rec2sqlite: filename=rec2sqlite-1.0-py3-none-any.whl size=3758 sha256=77225f8b2444fb4143ffb2aa70ee22735eff591452ba777387cc10b42f21b6ac
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/pt/7nsl9k8d6q56bwj9nc6lydzh0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-_voecun1/wheels/8b/47/6c/df4c285c608c63e5b3d6df78ec193cf038b3d4a56f4e3b2420
Successfully built rec2sqlite
Installing collected packages: rec2sqlite
  Attempting uninstall: rec2sqlite
    Found existing installation: rec2sqlite 1.0
    Uninstalling rec2sqlite-1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled rec2sqlite-1.0
Successfully installed rec2sqlite-1.0
```

Then I went to another directory and wanted to run the main function. I entered `python3 rec2sqlite` and got the following output:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3: can't open file 'rec2sqlite': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What do I need to change in the source code and/or the commands I use in order to be able to run the [main function](https://bitbucket.org/altruix/rec2sqlite/src/i1/rec2sqlite/main.py) after installing the current version using `pip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4043007/399457) helped. To fix the error, I had to do following:

1. Put the main function code into the file `__main__.py`.
2. Install the package using `pip3 install .` from the project directory.
3. Use `python3 -m <moduleName>` (e. g. `python3 -m rec2sqlite`) to run the program installed in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

What happen when you run `python3 rec2sqlite` from inside the project directory?
If you have to run the it from another directory you could try with the full path to the directory `python3 /<path-to-project-directory>/rec2sqlite`

Comment: That's not the point of installing the module using pip. When I install a module with pip, I expect it to work from any directory.