# Run a python wheel from CLI as if it were a single script

Tags: python, package, python-wheel

I wish to make a python wheel to upload as a spark-submit job in Azure Databricks, but I can't validate my wheel is working.  I don't understand where or how a call to the wheel finds the `__main__` method.

How do I build the package and/or call the wheel file on the command line in a way that the main method gets run?

Below is a simple package I'm attempting; all it does is echo today's date.

Some of the commands I've tried to run the script:

```
python dist/today-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/
python dist/today-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/__main__
python dist/today-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/main
```

I've tried a lot of variations on naming the main file `main.py` and `__main__.py` as well as naming the method `main` or `__main__`, but everything gives me the same error:
`C:\Python391\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\<DIRECTORYPATH>\\dist\\today-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl'`

The package consists of an empty `__init__.py` and `main.py` which looks like:

```
import datetime

def main():
    print(f'Today is {datetime.date.today()}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My directory structure is:

```
Wheeltest
  |-- setup.py
  |-- today
       |-- __init__.py
       |-- __main__.py
```

I've unzipped the wheel file and can confirm that it has a top level of the folder `today` with the 2 py files inside it.
My setup.py file looks like this (I've also tried without an entry_points section):

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

VERSION = '0.0.1'
DESCRIPTION = 'today package.'
LONG_DESCRIPTION = 'today dist.'

# Setting up
setup(
    name='today',
    version=VERSION,
    author='Simon Norton',
    author_email='<xxxxxxxx@yyyyy.com>',
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description=LONG_DESCRIPTION,
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['main=today.__main__:main']
    },
    classifiers=['Development Status :: Testing',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows',
        'Operating System :: Linux']
)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: "how a call to the wheel finds the __main__ method" you probably mean `main` function as that's what you have in your code. The answer is it won't. The wheel file is a built distribution file, intended to be installed. It's not standalone. Usual use for it is as a lib, not an app. If you want to make it an app you need to wrap it with something that includes it and launches the entry point explicitly. Maybe a shell script or https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/ Naming your function `main` is just convention. Naming a file `__main__` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the wheel file must contain the top-level folder inside the wheel to find `__main__` From my Example, the top level folder is called "today":

```
C:\<DIRECTORYPATH>\\dist\\today-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl\\today
```

Comment: The whl file is a zip file plus manifest. Your directory structure includes a package `today` so when you run `python C:\<DIRECTORYPATH>\\dist\\today-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl\\today` you are just benefiting from python being able to take zip files. If you include certain dependencies in your wheel, e.g. those with platform specific C libs, this won't work.  Wheel is not ideal for spark-submit unless it is just a simple build. Databricks jobs API 2.1 has a new `python_wheel_task`. It would be installed e.g. `pip install <path-to-wheel>` and has `package_name` and `entry_point` attributes.

Comment: The other ways to run wheels in databricks all involve installing it as a library on your cluster first. You can then use a python script task or notebook task to import your library and then run the entrypoint of your choosing. I'm guessing the new `python_wheel_task` will just create the dummy script.py to import and run your library for you. Check out the possible `tasks` in the API docs https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsCreate