# ImportError attempted relative import with no known parent

Tags: python

Based on some answers I try to be more specific.
I want to import the print and the models AND code in my main.py

I know the question gets asked a lot, but still I could not figure out whats wrong with my code!
I have a project directory like this

```
-project
   --__init__py
   --main.py
   --print.py
   --requests
        --__init__.py
        --models.py
        --code.py
```

i want to import from print.py and * from requests
Therefore I tried to add these lines in main.py

```
from . import print
#or
import print

#for requests I tried
import os.path
import sys
sys.path.append('./requests')
from requests import *
```

all of those lines cause the same **ImportError attempted relative import with no known parent** ,

using Python 39
anyone an idea where the problem is?
I am very confused that this seems not to work, was it possible in older versions?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely not be doing anything with `sys.path`.  If you are using a correct Python package structure, the import system should handle everything like this.

From the directory structure you described, `project` would be the name of your package.  So when using your package in some external code you would do

```
import package
```

or to use a submodule/subpackage

```
import project.print
import project.requests
```

and so on.

For modules inside the package you can use relative imports.  When you write

> i want to import from print.py and * from requests Therefore I tried

it's not clear *from where* you want to import them, because this is important for relative imports.

For example, in `project/main.py` to import the `print` module you could use:

```
from . import print
```

But if it's from `project/requests/code.py` you would use

```
from .. import print
```

As an aside, "print" is probably not a good name for a module, since if you import the print module it will shadow the `print()` built-in function.

Comment: The thing is, I want to use the modules within the project, so import them to the main.py. Note: print is not the real name!

Comment: So in `main.py` you would use `from . import print` and so on.

Comment: As you wrote how to use the relative imports, thats exactly what I wanted to do and is not working.

Comment: I think you may need to provide more details as to exactly what you did.  In what code did you write the import statements you showed?

Comment: The error you're getting is one that would be occurring if you attempt a relative import from a module that is not in a package.

Comment: I wrote the import statements in my main.py

Comment: How are you using main.py?  As written, you would not be able to write, e.g. `python project/main.py`.  If that's what you're doing then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68832223/982257) is correct.  What you can do instead is create a `__main__.py` and run `python -m project` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36320295/982257)

Comment: Basically, if you are running `python project/main.py` it does not get imported by the import system as part of the package, but rather as the special `__main__` module.  This means package-relative imports won't work because as far as the import system is concerned the `__main__` module is not part of any package (except in the special case of `packagename/__main__.py`).  Alternatively, in `main.py` you can use absolute imports instead of relative imports.

Answer (score 0):

Your main file should be outside the 'project'-directory to use that as a package.
Then, from your main file, you can import using from `project.print import ...`.

Within the project-package, relative imports are possible.

Comment: Not necessarily--they haven't explained exactly what `main.py` is or how it's intended to be used.