# How to run a module with gunicorn?

Tags: python, flask, module, gunicorn

I have a flask application that I have configured as a python module.

To explain further, this is a simplified structure of my project:

```
project_dir
  ven
  dir_a
      dir_b
           flask_app
                 __init__.py
                 __main__.py
```

```
# __main__.py
.
.
.
app = create_app(...)
client = Client(app)
.
.
.
print("Hello World")
running_app = app.run("0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

When I want to run my application, I hit `python -m dir_a.dir_b.flask_app`

Now I want to run it with gunicorn.

For your reference, this is a sample of running gunicorn

```
gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 **wsgi:server**
```

**If I want to run the application, from project_dir I run**

`python -m dir_a.dir_b.flask_app`

How should I run my application with gunicorn in my case?

Please note that I want "Hello World" to be printed before running the application

---

What I have tried:

```
gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 dir_a.dir_b.flask_app:running_app
```

I then removed the line `running_app = app.run("0.0.0.0", port=5000)`
and tried

```
gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 dir_a.dir_b.flask_app:app
```

and

```
gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 dir_a.dir_b.flask_app:create_app(...)
```

None of them worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell gunicorn what app to run

The `app.run()` method is for the development server, so first you’ll have to comment it out or just delete it.

And then

```
gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 dir_a.dir_b.flask_app:app
```

Or you could import the app further up in the module.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: btw, this is not answering my question

Comment: No need to edit the question, I meant in the code. 

Basically, app.run() will start Flask’s development server, it’s decent for development, but like you probably read, gunicorn or uWSGI are better for prod. 

So step one to running an app with gunicorn is not starting the development server. 

Then you just point gunicorn to the right app (that same app whose app.run() you removed).

Comment: please look at this tutorial, it is doing what I do https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-ml-models-using-flask-gunicorn-nginx-docker-9b32055b3d0

Comment: Ok, see my edits they show the exact specifications you’ve listed. By the way, this questions has been asked many times before.

Comment: the point is that I have other pieces of code that are in my __main__.py file and I want them to be run. Is your solution going to run them as well?

Comment: Is Hello World going to be printed?

Comment: I have never used a `__main__.py` file before. All the code you need run in a module should be in `__init__.py` or other files imported by `__init__.py`. As long as you put things in `__init__.py`, they’ll be run on import.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py

Comment: Thank you for the link, my point still remains true, file is run on import, you shouldn’t start development server, and start with `gunicorn -t 1 [other options] module.flask:app`. 
https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html

Comment: I should not do `app.run("0.0.0.0", port=5000)` in production ? Why not?
What I do is that run it inside a docker container and bind ports, for example with `-p 3000:5000`, and my application is accessible on port 3000

Comment: I tested what you advised and it did not work. I have reflected it in the edit of the question

Comment: You should not do `app.run(…)` in production because it’s the [development server](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/server/#development-server). You need to use a better options for prod, they are listed [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/) and gunicorn is [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#gunicorn), my best guess is `__main__.py` is not executed by gunicorn only by python when you run module as program, which is why my `__init__.py` comment is valid, move your code to imported files and retry, that’s all I have.