# How to package a Python wheel to be executable as cli using poetry?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-wheel, python-poetry

#### Problem

I would like to distribute a python package using poetry and make it executable as a cli, just like `black`, `pipenv`, `poetry`, `flake8` and friends.

Example usage would be:

```
python -m my-package [args]
```

#### Configuration

So far I have been succesful in building a wheel and installing it on a docker image using the following configuration:

`pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-package
version = "0.1.0"
description = "A cli tool"
authors = []
packages = [
    { include = "src/main.py" },
]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Build commands:

```
poetry build -f wheel
poetry export -o dist/requirements.txt
```

Docker image:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim as base

COPY dist/requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /requirements.txt
ARG APP_VERSION
COPY dist/my-package-$APP_VERSION-py3-none-any.whl .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --no-deps my-package-$APP_VERSION-py3-none-any.whl
```

Built using the following command:

```
docker build -t my-package:latest --build-arg APP_VERSION=$(poetry version -s) .
```

And run using the following command:

```
docker run -it my-package:latest /usr/local/bin/python -m my-package
```

Which results in:

```
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named my-package
```

While locally I can execute it by doing:

```
cd src
python main.py [args]
```

#### Concluding question

How can I install/package a wheel to make it executable as a cli?

#### EDIT

Additional logs:

```
╰─ docker build -t my-package:latest --build-arg APP_VERSION=0.1.0 .
[+] Building 1.9s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                   
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 353B                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8-slim                                                          0.9s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8-slim@sha256:0f6d6953c6612786ed05aaf1de7151dbbb0cea6bc83687040d5f15377be7ef64    0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 6.12kB                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] COPY dist/requirements.txt /requirements.txt                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /requirements.txt                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [4/5] COPY dist/my-package-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl .                                                              0.0s
 => [5/5] RUN pip install --user --no-cache-dir --no-deps my-package-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl                                 0.9s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:4f41ba75b6bbacd33d64a06eed921c1ca8aeca55e9340536b9208fcb694826dd                                0.0s 
 => => naming to my-package:latest                                                                                          0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
'package' took 2.9720 sec


╰─ docker run -it my-package:latest /bin/bash
root@f61d2505e762:/# python -m  my-package
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named  my-package
root@f61d2505e762:/# python -m my-package
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named my-package
root@f61d2505e762:/# pip freeze > req.txt
root@f61d2505e762:/# cat req.txt
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.9
idna==3.3
my-package @ file:///my-package-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
psycopg2-binary==2.9.2
requests==2.26.0
urllib3==1.26.7
```

Comment: Hi, what happens with "RUN pip install **--user** --no-cache..."?

Comment: Hi Laurent! Same behaviour unfortunately. I updated the OP with some logs

Comment: I also confirm that if I install black as a dep and run `python -m black` in the container, then black runs properly

Comment: Hey @PhilippeHebert, did you ever figure out how to compile your click cli into an standalone executable?

Comment: Not that I know of, I can't find any trace of similar code in our monorepo. I figure we found an alternate way (or dropped the idea to run whatever this was as a separate microservice)

Answer (score 4):

Running a python application via `python -m app` uses a different mechanism compared to having a command `app`.

Let's assume the following project structure:

```
demo-cli
├── demo_cli
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── cli.py
├── poetry.lock
└── pyproject.toml
```

**`pyproject.toml`**:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "demo-cli"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["finswimmer <finswimmer77@gmail.com>"]
packages = [{include = "demo_cli"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
demo-cli = "demo_cli.cli:say_hello"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

**`cli.py`**:

```py
def say_hello():
    print("Hello")
```

**`__main__.py`**:

```py
from demo_cli import cli

cli.say_hello()
```

This part in the `pyproject.toml` give us a command `demo-cli` by defining the method which should be executed:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
demo-cli = "demo_cli.cli:say_hello"
```

The content of the `__main__.py` is triggered on a `python -m demo_cli`. So we need to add the method call there. More detailed information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py).