# "No module named x.__main__; 'x' is a package and cannot be directly executed" when using entry_points / console_scripts

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi, command-line-tool

I have [this CLI tool](https://github.com/Antrikshy/Rackfocus) called Rackfocus. I've published to PyPI, and I'm reasonably sure it worked just fine before. When I try to run it with current versions of Python on Mac, I get the error:

```
No module named rackfocus.__main__; 'rackfocus' is a package
and cannot be directly executed
```

All I want is one package with one entry point that users can download and use using pip.

Based on tutorials, I have this in [setup.py](https://github.com/Antrikshy/Rackfocus/blob/master/setup.py):

```
packages=['rackfocus']
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': [
        'rackfocus=rackfocus.run:main'
    ]
}
```

And I have a `rackfocus.run:main` function, an **init**.py and everything.  What's wrong?

You can reproduce this locally:

1. Clone my repo.
2. Create and activate a virtualenv (optional).
3. `pip3 install -e .`
4. `python3 -m rackfocus`

Comment: The problem isn't that you are "using entry_points / console_scripts". The problem is that you are **not** doing so; or rather, you are trying to run the program in a way that *ignores* that aspect of the setup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': [
        'rackfocus=rackfocus.run:main'
    ]
}
```

This tells the packaging system to *create a wrapper executable* named `rackfocus`. That executable will automatically handle all the necessary steps to get Python off the ground, find the `run` module in the `rackfocus` package, find its `main` function and call it.

You run the executable like `rackfocus` (if you are using a virtual environment, it should be on the path already), not `python -m rackfocus`.

Using `python -m rackfocus` is *completely unrelated to that* (it doesn't even have anything to do with packaging, and can easily be used with code that hasn't been installed yet). It doesn't use the wrapper; instead, it simply attempts to *execute the `rackfocus` module*. But in your case, `rackfocus` *isn't* a module; it's a package. The error message means exactly what it says.

You would want `python -m rackfocus.run` to execute the `run` module - but of course, that still doesn't actually call `main()` (just like it wouldn't with `python rackfocus/main.py` - though the `-m` approach [is more powerful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/); in particular, it allows your relative imports to work).

The error message says `rackfocus.__main__` because you [can make a package runnable by giving it a `__main__` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36320295).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this. Turns out I was using the system Python that comes with macOS and the PATH is set up such that pip-installed packages aren't in it. I vaguely remembered `python3 -m ...` being the recommended new way to execute packages from somewhere and just tried that. 

I just installed my own Python from Brew, then installed my package through _that_ pip3. Running the package as a command works out of the box with this installation!

Comment: "the system Python that comes with macOS and the PATH is set up such that pip-installed packages aren't in it" Yes; I assume this is a security feature for OSes that come with Python pre-deployed, so that you don't disrupt a Python installation needed for critical system tasks. "`python3 -m ...` being the recommended new way to execute packages from somewhere and just tried that." To execute (actually executable) packages (or more commonly, modules), yes. But that's *not actually what you were trying to do*.

Comment: "Running the package as a command works out of the box with this installation!" As I said, you don't need to install your code to use it with `python -m`.  You *do* need to understand how the packaging system works, no matter what you are trying to do. You should also read up on virtual environments, while you're at it.

Comment: Can you illustrate with an example module that _should_ be called with `python -m`? Why is Rackfocus not an executable package? What would you call it instead?

Comment: Like I said, `rackfocus` is a package. It just isn't an executable one. To be executable you would have to take the steps described in the last link. `python -m` is useful for any module that you'd call directly, like `python whatever.py` - the differences are as explained at the other link.