# Question about console scripts pip package

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to publish my first pip package, but this isn't very easy. I have the following file structure for my project:

```
src
  main.py
  about.py
  __init__.py
LICENSE
pyproject.toml
README.md
setup.cfg
```

How would I go about starting the `main.py`-file using a console script, defined in `setup.cfg`?
The `main.py`-file doesn't have a main function. `about.py` is an extra part of my code to show a simple about screen.

Comment: Can you provide a more descriptive tittle for the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a python package with a different name (src is not recommended) and name your main file as [`__main__.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py). This way, when you execute your package with `python package_name` the `__main__.py` file will be executed

For example:

```
src
    package_name
        __main__.py
        about.py
        __init__.py
LICENSE
pyproject.toml
README.md
setup.cfg
```