# Python module not found even though init file exists

Tags: python

I know this question has been asked quite a few times, but I've done everything according to the book and it still doesn't seem to work.

My Python project structure is like so:

```
project
..src
....infra
......__init__.py
......agent
........__init__.py
........agent_api.py
....tests
......__init__.py
......test_auth.py
....utils
```

In `test_auth.py`, I want to reference `agent_api`, like this:

```
from infra.agent import agent_api
```

However, running `test_auth.py` from either the project root or the `src` directory yield the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'infra'`.

Comment: Please show us the exact command you run `test_auth.py` with, and from which directory.

Comment: @blhsing `src >> python3 tests/test_authentication.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/projects/auto/src/tests/test_authentication.py", line 1, in <module>
    from infra import agent_api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'infra'`

Comment: you need a relative import, e.g. `from ..infra.agent import agent_api`

Comment: So you mistyped `from infra.agent import agent_api` as `from infra import agent_api`.

Comment: In your question you say you want to do `from infra.agent import agent_api`, but your error message suggests your code actually attempts `from infra import agent_api`.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Now getting `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Comment: @slothrop same error.

Comment: @user20395797 I think this means you're using an older python, and thus you need to explicitly make it known that your project and src folders are packages by creating an (empty if desired) `__init__.py` file in each. If you are NOT working in the context of this being a package, then you cannot use relative imports, and you should be rethinking your file structure. OR use an absolute import, which would depend on the path from which you are running things.

Comment: see also this old answer of mine, which might shed some more light: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64787998/4183191

Comment: @user20395797 One more thing to: if you want imports to be evaluated relative to the working directory (rather than the directory of the script you invoke), then you need to run with the `-m` flag: `python3 -m tests.test_authentication`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch

Comment: Alternatively, if you're trying to run these as simple scripts, then for `from infra` to work, you should be trying to run this from the 'src' directory, and run the test_auth.py script via its full path, i.e. `python3 tests/test_auth.py`. This causes your base directory to be src, from which the `infra` package can be found.