# How to make a python package's __init__.py file execute when debugging the __main__.py file?

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

If I execute `python -m some_package` on the command line, with `some_package/__init__.py` containing `print("hello __init__.py")` and `some_package/__main__.py` containing `print("hello __main__.py")`, then both lines get printed, each once. But if I'm debugging `__main__.py` in an IDE (VSCode), only `__main__.py` executes, which would break behavior for anything other than a simple example. If I attempt to debug `some_package/__init__.py` instead, `__main__.py` never gets executed. How to fix this?

Update:
I just realized, if I import some_package from another script, only `__init__.py` is executed. So I guess I'm missing some important statements in `__init__.py` and that I should initiate debugging on that file instead?

Update 2:
From [Python Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) I'm starting to question the purpose of **main**.py altogether?

Answer (score 1):

`__init__.py` is executed when your module is imported, as you noted when importing some_package. Importing your package does not happen when you run the module directly from the command line.

`__main__.py` can be run directly (eg. `python -m __main__.py`), or as the module execution when run as a folder or zipfile from the command line (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py) for additional explanation). Basically, if you have a `__main__.py` file, you can call `python some_package` and it will execute `some_package/__main__.py`

using `python -m some_package` to run a module runs both your `__init__.py` and `__main__.py` when targeting a module or file directly (see [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch) for additional explanation of the -m flag)

Now that we've covered what is executed in these scenarios, can you elaborate on what you're having issues with during debugging, with code samples please?

Comment: thx this contained multiple hints+references in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

`some_package/__main__.py` is only needed if you want to execute your package as a module (`python -m some_package`).

When importing a package, or a module in that package, be it via `import some_package`, `import some_package.some_module`, or `python -m some_package` (which is implicitly `import some_package.__main__ as __main__` or thereabouts), the package's `__init__` is also executed.

I don't know much about VSCode's debugger, but presumably you can tell it to debug the whole program, and tell it to do `python -m some_package` as the entry point, or if that doesn't seem to be possible, write a simple `run_my_package.py` (outside the package!) which contains just `import some_package.__main__`, and debug that.