# can we call a python file consisting of only function definition as a script?

Tags: python, scripting

If there is a file in python with a function definition only and i don't call that function in that file.. is it a script or module? For eg:-

```
def func():
    print('Hey')
```

Comment: That would be a module. You can import it to other modules / scripts and use this code in it.

Comment: yes its a module..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a module and a script in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996110/what-is-the-difference-between-a-module-and-a-script-in-python)

Comment: Every python files can be called `script`. Because it is a scripting language. May be you wanted to know if the given file is a `module` or `package`?

Answer (score 1):

Any python file is a module which you can [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import).

According to python doc:

> A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended.

And also an empty python file is a module, although useless.

And any python file is a also script.

A python file containing only a function definition is a script, but it will not do anything.

There's not much emphasis in making such a distinction in the Python world. Usually, a script is supposed to execute some code, while a module is a library of functions and classes to be imported and executed by some other script.

There's a special variable `__name__` which you can check to tell if the current script is being run directly in a python interpreter (in that case will have the value `"__main__"`), or not (i.e. is imported by some other script), e.g.:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this script is being run directly in the interpreter
    # i.e.  python this_script.py
    #
    # this block will not be executed when this is import'ed
```

Read more at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: but is this a script?

Comment: Yes, any python file is also a script. There's not much emphasis in making such a distinction in the Python world. Usually, a script is supposed to do something, while a module is a library of functions to be imported and executed by some other script.

Answer (score 1):

Python considers any python script file as module. Hence in you case also it will consider your python file as a module and that will be utilize as below:-

Suppose your python script module file name is util.py

```
import util

util.func()
```